# Do I have to apply Bonferroni correction for U-test

Tags: wilcoxon-mann-whitney-test, bonferroni

I believe my question might be quiet easy for you to answer. I tried to do some research on that topic myself but failed to come to a conclusion. 
If I understood correctly, Bonferroni correction is used for repeated pairwise comparison within a dataset. My question is, if that applies for my data. 
I measured the number of mass peaks of different analytes before and after an event to see if the event has an influence on the number of measured peaks. Measurements before and after the event were made for different analytes and I compared only analytes of the same type before and after the event using U-test, not analyte a to analyte b. In case I would compare all analytes pairwise before and after the event, I am sure I would have to carry out Bonferroni correction but in my case I'm rather uncertain since the different analytes are only similiar in the event they were exposed to.

```
 Before the event       After the event
  Analyte  Peaks        Analyte   Peak
    a       120           a       130
    b       75            b       70
    a       111           a       120
    b       82            b       80
    a       125           a       122
    a       114           a       127
    b       70            b       73
    b       69            b       76
```

This is an example of my data. I would only compare a from before the event to a after the event and b from before to b after. In my actual data there are 9 analytes and the general question is if the event has an effect on the number of peaks. So I'm repeatedly testing the same hypothesis - is this a reason for applying Bonferroni correction. 
Would the answer change if I did a comparison between the whole data set before and after the event?

Comment: So are there repeated measures for the same analyte (i.e., there is a single analyte A which is exposed to different events and measured each time) or are different individual analytes from a class tested individually (there are 10 analytes belonging to class A, and each is exposed to each event a single time)?

Comment: Hello @Upper_Case, I missed your comment, which is why I answer this late. Example: I have 20 analytes of A. 10 of these will be be measured before the event and by measuring them, they will be lost. To the remaining 10 the event will be applied and then be measured. Based on this I want to know if the event in general has an effect on these kind of analytes. The event in this case is the storage of the measured material over a certain time and no repeated measurement of the same sample.